# KeyError when trying to create a nested route

Tags: python, django, generics, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a https://dog.ceo/dog-api/ clone and I am running into a small problem.

Here is my code:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Breed(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=150)


      def __str__(self):
          return self.name

class BreedImage(models.Model):
    breed = models.ForeignKey(Breed, related_name='BreedImages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    breedImage = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
```

Serializers

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Breed, BreedImage

class BreedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = Breed
        fields = ['name', 'BreedImages']

class BreedSerializerRandom(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = Breed
        fields = ['id', 'BreedImages']
```

Views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Breed
from .serializers import BreedSerializer, BreedSerializerRandom
from rest_framework.parsers import FileUploadParser, FormParser, MultiPartParser
# Create your views here.

class BreedList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)
    queryset = Breed.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BreedSerializer
    pagination_class = None


class BreedDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Breed.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BreedSerializer
    pagination_class = None

class BreedDetailRandom(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    serializer_class = BreedSerializerRandom

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Breed.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['id']).order_by('?')[0]
```

Urls

```
from django.urls import path
from Breed import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('breeds/', views.BreedList.as_view()),
    path('breeds/<int:pk>/', views.BreedDetail.as_view()),
    path('breeds/<int:pk>/random', views.BreedDetailRandom.as_view()),
]
```

My error is:

```
KeyError at /breeds/1/random

'id'
```

I am trying to create a nested url to get a random image from specific dog breed I have on my API, and I am unsure what is the problem.

Comment: you don't have id in kwargs but pk

Answer (score 1):

your URL has pk as argument

```
path('breeds/<int:pk>/random', views.BreedDetailRandom.as_view())
```

but in view you are looking for id

```
return Breed.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['id']).order_by('?')[0]
```

---

sidenote -> order_by('?') is inefficient